# Metatags module not rendering tokens in content

Tags: tokens, meta-tags

We created custom tokens for a site and they are included in things like titles and summaries, so are picked up by the [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. However, when I look at search results in Google, I see the variable [token] and not the rendered value in the search results.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You need to verify that they are being rendered; you can always check this by viewing the source code of your pages. There is no way we can really help without the code you used to provide those tokens - I suggest copying it here so others can have a look.

Comment: Aram: The point is they are not being rendered by the metatags module, but are being rendered on page. I have most filters set to render tokens. I had not created custom summaries so summaries were being auto-generated and contained tokens, resulting in results like:

Overnight | Good Times Summer Day Camp
Wisconsin Overnight Good Times offers an overnight experience on Friday, [libertyville:overnightdatetext], for children ages 8 and up at our very own campsite in ...

Brochure | Good Times Summer Day Camp
[libertyville:thiscampyear] Brochure Download our [libertyville:thiscampyear] Brochure!